# Generating mock data for Geofire

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have used Mockaroo but don’t see where I can generate mock data and get the Geofire key. Is there a way to generate mock data that includes the Geofire keys? Another function I have is dependent on having that Geofire key.